# I am struggling to connect these three rules together

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm having issues connecting the following three rules together.

```
countingCombo([H|T], Sequence2) :-
   fact1(H, Sequence),
   append(Sequence, Sequence2, Sequence3),
   countingCombo(T, Sequence3).
countingCombo([], Combination) :-
   print(Combination),
   membersofCombo(Combination, X, C).

membersofCombo(List, X, C) :-
   sort(List, List1),
   member(X, List1),
   count(List, X, C).

count([], X, 0).
count([X|T], X, Y) :-
   count(T, X, Z),
   Y is 1+Z.
count([X1|T], X, Z) :-
   X1 \= X,
   count(T, X, Z).
```

countingcombo creates an appended list. membersofcombo, sorts that list and then produces each member of the original appended list, count rule then counts the occurences of each memeber.

membersofcombo and count work together, but I can't get countingcombo to connect to members of combo.

Comment: @repeat Its from my database, each one follows this format fact(Name,List).

Comment: @repeat  namelist(g,[g,b,h]),  namelist(g,[f,b,g]), namelist(h,[g,l,h]), namelist(r,[g,h,b]), namelist(r,[l,h,h]), namelist( r,[f,l,f]).   Some names have multiple lists.

Comment: So `fact1/2` is `namelist/2`?

Comment: @repeat yes, i intended to make it sound generic

Comment: So where are your sample queries?

Comment: You should really hotlink the questions and answers from where you get the code that you show in a question.

Comment: @Boris. Good point! So I'm not the only one who had a deja-vu when seeing `count/3`:)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues with your code:

- <s>Are you aware that `combination` is **not** a variable (standing for some list)?</s>

  ```
  rule1([], combination) :-
     print(combination),
     rule2(combination, X, C).
  ```
- <s>Choose better predicate names: `rule1`, `rule2`, and `rule3` don't tell me nothing...</s>
- Use [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) in the implementation of `count/3`!
- Eliminate the singleton variable `X` in clause `count([], X, 0).`
  Quite likely, you meant to write `count([], _, 0).`
- <s>Provide an implementation of `count/3`. Is it `rule3/3`?</s>

Comment: Yes, typo. Meant to be Combination with a capital. The code still doesn't work however. Editted the question.